# Refresh token for google calendar API

Tags: python, api, calendar

Hi I am using the google calendar API for a school project and my tokens have expired and I don't know how to refresh them. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when a token expires, make a new one using the same process and replace the old one in your code with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example [1] depending on the programming language you're using, for Python should be similar to the following:

```
...
developer_token: INSERT_DEVELOPER_TOKEN_HERE
client_id: INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID_HERE
client_secret: INSERT_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE
refresh_token: INSERT_OAUTH2_REFRESH_TOKEN_HERE
login_customer_id: INSERT_LOGIN_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE
...
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/refresh-token